# How do I get an attribute from an instance while in a class?

Tags: java, class, object, instance

For example, I have two methods inside of a class named "Wizard":

```
public class Wizard
{
    public int getAttack()
    {
        return attack;
    }

    public void getHitBy(Object var_of_attacker)
    {
        int attackPower = var_of_attacker.getAttack() - defense;

        if (attackPower > 0)
        {
            health -= attackPower;
            System.out.println(name + " took " + attackPower + " damage!");
        } else {
            System.out.println(name + " managed to completely block the attack!");
        }

        if (health <= 0)
        {
            alive = false;
            System.out.println("Oh, no! \n" + name + " died!");
        }
    }
}
```

If I decide to make two instances of the class, and I want to get one of them to attack the other, how would I get the attack attribute from the instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd have to pass the other object as a parameter. You can then access the parameter's methods with the dot (`.`) operator, just instead of `this`, use the parameter's name.

Consider that a program could have hundreds of objects; how would the compiler know *which* other object you want to look at?

Maybe I don't understand your question, as you are already passing an object?